# Do the decoration multipliers stack?

Tags: pokemon-quest

In Pokemon Quest, decorations acquired provide a bonus, whether they are set out at your camp or not. What's unclear to me is, do decoration bonuses stack? For example, the Dodrio Tent effect is "Size of Gray Ingredient Drops X1.5", and the Mechanical Tauros effect is "Size of Gray Ingredient Drops X2".

So, does owning both mean I get X3.5, or is it pointless to own the Dodrio Tent?

Answer (score 2):

They stack, but having the Dodrio Tent and Mechanical Tauros won't grant you X3.5 grey elements drop, but X1.5X2 = X3 drops 
Source : https://www.polygon.com/guides/2018/6/5/17429544/pokemon-quest-guide-spend-money and own experience with the game

Answer (score 1):

According to [this site](https://dotesports.com/the-op/news/pokemon-quest-decorations-pm-tickets-experience-ingredients-guide-24677), they do stack! I had to dig a little to find it.